# Don't put test assemblies in output on TFS

Tags: unit-testing, tfs

Is there any way not to put test assemblies in the output?
In other words I'd like to run afterbuild tests but I don't need test assemblies in output.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you don't have the assemblies you cant run the tests.

If you are looking for a similar solution to the web applications _PublishedWebApplication folder you can find a _PublishedApplications package on NuGet to help you out.

Comment: But maybe I can remove test dlls after running tests?

Comment: Sure, but why? Your test dll's are part of the build asset and are of value to your organisation.

Comment: @MrHinsh The question would probably be better phrased as "How do I avoid **deploying** my test assemblies" :)

Comment: As described in the answer use the _PublishedApplications Nuget package to have the build system automatically create a folder for each application in your solution with only the files required for that app.